# Date is getting converted to number, while making html of datafrane

Tags: html, r, dataframe

While converting the data frame to HTML, Date is getting converted to a number.

```
library("xtable")
print(xtable(Data), type="html", file="Data.html",timestamp=date())
```

The first column of this data frame is in Date format, which is getting converted to a number.

Comment: Post your code and dataframe. How are you converting?

Comment: Please put additional information in your question (not in a comment), i.e. **edit your question:** https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47303682/edit

Comment: I am getting warning messages when I try to recreate your example. It is important to report all the results of your attempts.

Answer (score 2):

You could try `tableHTML` which handles dates. As a quick example:

```
library(tableHTML)
Data <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = as.Date('2017-01-01'))
mytable <- tableHTML(Data, rownames = FALSE)
mytable
```

[image]

And to write it in a file, you can use:

```
write_tableHTML(mytable, file = 'Data.html')
```